# Is this wrapper around an HashMap thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class LockMap {

    private final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            map.put(key, value);
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        try {
            lock.readLock().lock();
            return map.get(key);
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this map wrapper actually threadsafe?

Especially, considering the array backing the `HashMap` is not marked as `volatile`, which guarantee do I have that a `put` done by a thread is visible to another thread during a subsequent read?

---

I know that a `ConcurrentHashMap` would be a much better choice over this simplistic wrapper

The goal of the question is to understand the impact of the lack of the `volatile` keyword on the array backing the `HashMap` implementation

Comment: In a brute-force sense, this would be a thread-safe usage of HashMap. However, the level of functionality present is a bit bare-bones (only `#get` and `#put`). `volatile` is not necessary in this scenario. What's the actual use-case?

Comment: Lack of volatile is irrelevant. The locks provide the same happens-before guarantees. See the linked duplicate. Your impl is thread-safe.